# Google Fuel Station API/databases/geolocation fata for finding a fuel station

Tags: api, geolocation

I am working on a project for developing an iPhone app. We need to figure out the way to get the nearest fuel station list for a particular country.

See the description here.

you can google/search for fuel station API’s/databases or other geolocation data for each country. If you could create a spreadsheet with known/obvious API’s, it would be helpful for us to know whats out there.  As I say, if we can figure out where GPS devices get their fuel data, that would be one good option for us.

Please help me know what do you think are the possible API's that I could use.

Comment: Sure... just a second and we'll do your work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

http://www.mygasfeed.com/keys/api

You might have a bit more luck if you try searching for the term "gas stations" instead of "fuel stations." At least, where I live "gas station" is commonly used, but "fuel station" is not.

Comment: Hi @GGG I have considered using Google Places API as its global and it supports the Gas station search. I am unable to locate ESSO gas stations using this API in netherlands. There are a lot of apps out there. I am sure there must be a way to get the details of those station. I found a way to download the data and feed the app. (http://www.euromap.be/esso/ExportStations.aspx) but this is a Excel sheet and I would really love to have API.